How to manually order segments of a stacked bar plot for each sample individually
I have a total of 14 samples and the microbial diversity of each sample, I am trying to plot their relative proportions in a stack bar plot in Rstudio to shows the general diversity of microbial species present within each sample.
I am trying to achieve the following

Display the different species of microbes in order of their respective proportions in an individual-specific manner
I also would like to position unidentified/insignificant species grouped together as 'Others' at the top of each barplot

I am rather new to coding as such I have been relying very much on ChatGPT to craft most of my codes up, unfortuntately I am still unable to resolve this issue
Here is my code
data <- read_excel("/Users/samuellee/Desktop/R Data/Processed data/(3) Symbiont R analysis/ITS2 sequence types.xlsx", sheet = "TT_90")
data$Species <- factor(data$Species)
data$`Clam id` <- factor(data$`Clam id`)
str(data)

# Define species groups
clado_species <- c('12891_C', '12963_C', '2349_C', '26266_C', '28556_C', '28557_C', '28558_C', '36371_C', '3882_C', '3935_C', '3960_C', '3961_C', '4127_C', 'C1', 'C1n', 'C1q', 'C3', 'C3u', 'C3v', 'C66', 'C66a', 'C89', 'C91', 'C93a')
duru_species <- c('D4', '16761_D', '16814_D', '16901_D', '16995_D', '17046_D', '17184_D', '17278_D', '3908_D', '3143_D', '34296_D', '7879_D', 'D1', 'D12', 'D13', 'D3', 'D3a', 'D5', 'D9b')
symbio_species <- c("3845_A")
other_species <- c("Others")

# Define ColorBrewer palettes
clado_colors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "PuBu"))(length(clado_species))  # Generate colors based on the actual number of species
duru_colors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "OrRd"))(length(duru_species))    # Same here for Duru
symbio_color <- "#2ca02c"  # Green for Symbio
other_color <- "black"

# Create color mapping
color_mapping <- c(
  setNames(clado_colors, clado_species),      # Colors for Clado species
  setNames(duru_colors, duru_species),        # Colors for Duru species
  setNames(rep(symbio_color, length(symbio_species)), symbio_species),  # Green for Symbio
  setNames(rep(other_color, length(other_species)), other_species)  # Black for 'Others'
)

# Reorder Species within each Clam based on proportion
data <- data %>%
  group_by(`Clam id`) %>%
  mutate(Species = fct_reorder(Species, Proportion, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Species = fct_relevel(Species, "Others", after = Inf) %>%
         fct_rev())

str(data)
# Check reordering (for debugging)
print(data %>%
  group_by(`Clam id`) %>%
  summarize(Order = paste(Species, collapse = ", ")))

# Plot
its2plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = `Clam id`, y = Proportion, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +  # Ensure stacking
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_mapping) +  # Apply custom colors
  labs(x = "Clam ID", y = "Proportion", fill = "Species") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))  # Rotate x-axis labels

print(its2plot)
ggsave("its2plot.png", plot = its2plot, width = 8, height = 6, units = "in", dpi = 300)

Here is the data set that I am working with for  reference
> dput(data)
structure(list(`Clam id` = c("B13", "B13", "B13", "B13", "B13", 
"A9", "A9", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B10", "B10", "B10", 
"B14", "B14", "B14", "B14", "B14", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", 
"B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", 
"B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "B18", "A7", "A7", 
"A8", "A8", "A8", "A6", "A6", "A6", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", 
"B12", "B12", "B12", "B12", "B12", "A5", "A5", "A5", "B16", "B16", 
"B16", "B16", "B16", "B16", "B16", "B16", "B15", "B15", "B15", 
"B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", "B15", 
"B15", "B15"), Species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 
9L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 25L, 5L, 25L, 6L, 5L, 25L, 26L, 5L, 25L, 27L, 
28L, 5L, 25L, 6L, 29L, 28L, 5L, 30L, 31L, 5L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 1L, 37L, 5L, 38L, 39L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 14L, 45L, 5L), levels = c("D4", "D5", "D9b", "3143_D", 
"Others", "D13", "C3v", "C3", "3960_C", "C1q", "D12", "16761_D", 
"C1n", "C1", "3935_C", "17278_D", "C89", "3961_C", "34296_D", 
"16901_D", "17184_D", "16995_D", "17046_D", "16814_D", "C66", 
"12891_C", "3882_C", "12963_C", "C66a", "C93a", "36371_C", "D3", 
"D3a", "D1", "7879_D", "3845_A", "3908_D", "C91", "4127_C", "C3u", 
"28556_C", "26266_C", "28557_C", "28558_C", "2349_C"), class = "factor"), 
    Proportion = c(0.359222051433613, 0.331850587087535, 0.171036263574852, 
    0.0442721959801818, 0.0936189019238185, 0.921458884215254, 
    0.0785411157847458, 0.873709821538493, 0.0250346215273611, 
    0.0234967369928517, 0.0777588199412937, 0.866716111215201, 
    0.0359960110057352, 0.0972878777790639, 0.824127906040564, 
    0.0471871079463971, 0.0211992183489764, 0.0204996139880998, 
    0.0869861536759624, 0.446964163402195, 0.107484380547375, 
    0.0479541700193955, 0.047245963019109, 0.0456997719831104, 
    0.0398264710161082, 0.0284766124811592, 0.0216874617711328, 
    0.0216207197106301, 0.0187841821392646, 0.0129442518452769, 
    0.0095700700038707, 0.00936984400378972, 0.00912512300369074, 
    0.00866905200350628, 0.00856893900346578, 0.00798680000323033, 
    0.00672240900271894, 0.00660004800266945, 0.0946995670383021, 
    0.948303755891408, 0.0516962441085919, 0.884840029526464, 
    0.0267894099842383, 0.0883705604892983, 0.874060834510106, 
    0.0295528509496252, 0.0963863145402687, 0.838186325215696, 
    0.0429409409378516, 0.0367851059467609, 0.0820876278996914, 
    0.60719606706223, 0.219747574179924, 0.0540957716306187, 
    0.0393806120421173, 0.0795799750851102, 0.887337718082343, 
    0.0329209554844701, 0.0797413264331864, 0.552183939429258, 
    0.163971785192249, 0.056235305020342, 0.044433894029457, 
    0.0307741002100828, 0.028287212887787, 0.0241273290087276, 
    0.0999864342220966, 0.384070361711374, 0.0999007688606952, 
    0.0947415058678894, 0.0895492878751296, 0.0455435899364926, 
    0.0408823109429924, 0.0386047649461683, 0.0349211459513048, 
    0.0156608726955815, 0.015463143650559, 0.014664904172505, 
    0.0144671751274824, 0.0136213342126638, 0.0979088340491623
    )), row.names = c(NA, -81L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


To stack each bar separately you could use the group aesthetic. To this end add a helper column to your data with the interaction of the x and the fill variables. Then arrange your data in the desired order and use fct_inorder to set the order of the helper column. Finally, map the helper column on the group aes.
library(tidyverse)

# Reorder Species within each Clam based on proportion
data <- data %>%
  # Arrange data
  arrange(
    `Clam id`,
    # Arange by proportion where I use an if_else to "assign"
    # he other category a proportion of 0 for sorting
    if_else(Species == "Others", 0, Proportion)
  ) %>%
  # Add a helper column for the grouping of each stacked bar
  mutate(group = fct_inorder(interaction(`Clam id`, Species)))

# Plot
ggplot(data, aes(
  x = `Clam id`, y = Proportion,
  fill = Species,
  # Map the helper column on the "group" aes
  group = group
)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = color_mapping
  ) +
  labs(x = "Clam ID", y = "Proportion", fill = "Species") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)
  )


